# How to unselect selected option-element in select-element using Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

**I have the following requirements:**

- I got two `FormControl` objects for select-elements `mainSelect` and `subSelect` that are `required`.
- `subSelect` changes depending on the value from `mainSelect`.
- When `mainSelect` changes to a value in which the value from `subSelect` isn't included `subSelect` needs to become `invalid` so the `FormGroup` both of the `FormControl`'s are part of becomes `invalid`, too.
- But if the value from `subSelect` is included `subSelect` needs to hold his actual value.

(A concrete example is described after the StackBlitz link.)

**My problem solving this requirement:**

If the value of `mainSelect` changes and the value of `subSelect` isn't included `subSelect` takes the first value of the list instead of becoming `null`/`invalid`.

So the **SOLUTION** would be if the selected value of 'subSelect' becomes null and no value is selected in the browser.

**What I tried so far:**

I tried to create a component and implement the `ControlValueAccessor` interface. Seems like here lies my problem. I think I don't really understand how that works.

I watched the following video on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CD_t3m2WMM8&amp=&index=15) and read articles ([1](https://blog.angularindepth.com/never-again-be-confused-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-forms-93b9eee9ee83), [2](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-nested-reactive-forms-using-cvas-b394ba2e5d0d)) related to `ControlValueAccessor`, but still couldn't solve my problem.

**This is part of my code:**

Also you can find it on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/JoeBeer/writeValue-demo)

**Example**

If in the browser `MainSelect` has the value `thirdMainSelect` and `SubSelect` has the value `fifthSubSelect` and `MainSelect` changes his value to `firstMainSelect` `SubSelect` should have no selected value.

**select.component.ts**

```
export class SomeObject {
  value: string;
  parameters: {[parameterName: string]: string} = {};
}

@Component({
  selector: "app-select",
  templateUrl: "./select.component.html",
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: SelectComponent,
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class SelectComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnChanges {
  @ViewChild("select", {static: true}) select: ElementRef;
  @Input() tableId: string;
  @Input() filter: { [parameterName: string]: string};

  returnedTable: SomeObject[];

  onChange: (_: any) => void;
  onTouched: () => void;

  selected: string;

  constructor(private tableService: TableService) { }

  loadTable(): void {
    this.tableService.getTable(this.tableId, this.filter)
      .subscribe(table => {
        this.returnedTable = table;
      });
  }

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.loadTable();
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  writeValue(value: string): void {
    this.selected = value;
  }
}
```

**select.component.html**

```
<select class="form-control" #select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
  <option *ngFor="let item of returnedTable" [value]="item.value" [selected]="selected === item.value">{{item.value}}</option>
</select>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  containerObject: ContainerObject;

  selectedMainValue: string;

  constructor(private tableService: TableService,
              private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.tableService.getContainerObject()
      .subscribe(containerObject => {
        this.containerObject = containerObject;
        this.selectedMainValue = containerObject.mainSelect;
        this.initForm();
      });
  }

  private initForm(): void {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      mainSelect: [this.containerObject.mainSelect, Validators.required],
      subSelect: [this.containerObject.subSelect, Validators.required]
    });
    this.subscribeToMainSelectChanged();
    this.subscribeToSubSelectChanged();
  }

  onSubmit(): void {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      this.containerObject.mainSelect = this.form.get("mainSelect").value;
      this.containerObject.subSelect = this.form.get("subSelect").value;
      this.tableService.saveContainerObject(this.containerObject);
    }
  }

  private subscribeToMainSelectChanged() {
    this.form.get("mainSelect").valueChanges
      .subscribe(mainSelect => {
        this.selectedMainValue = mainSelect;
        console.log(this.form.status);
      });
  }

  private subscribeToSubSelectChanged() {
    this.form.get("subSelect").valueChanges
      .subscribe(() => {
        console.log(this.form.status);
      });
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div>
  <form id="wrapper" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div id="left" class="form-group row">
      <label for="mainSelect" class="col-form-label col-sm-2">MainSelect</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <app-select
          id="mainSelect"
          formControlName="mainSelect"
          [tableId]="'mainSelectTable'"
          [filter]="{firstType: 'firstParameter'}"
        ></app-select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right" class="form-group row">
      <label for="subSelect" class="col-form-label col-sm-2">SubSelect</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <app-select
          id="subSelect"
          formControlName="subSelect"
          [tableId]="'firstParameter'"
          [filter]="{firstType: 'firstParameter', secondType: selectedMainValue}"></app-select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <button id="button" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You can do it just by setting the subselect to blank value whenever the main select values changes it is that simple

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. That's another requirement I missed to include. If the previous and new value of `mainSelect` includes the actual value of `subSelect`, the value of `subSelect` needs to stay valid. (I hope it's halfway clear what I'm trying to archive). I will edit my question to add this requirement to it.

Comment: It again simple just go through the sub list and check if the selected value is present in the sublist if yes then don't set the value again so that the value is maintained and if no then set it to ""

Comment: Would be great if you could post the code for your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while trying to solve this problem only using the `SelectComponent` and especially `writeValue`, the following code did the job:

I changed the `select.component.ts` as following:

```
export class SomeObject {
  value: string;
  parameters: {[parameterName: string]: string} = {};
}

@Component({
  selector: "app-select",
  templateUrl: "./select.component.html",
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: SelectComponent,
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class SelectComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnChanges {
  @ViewChild("select", {static: true}) select: ElementRef;
  @Input() tableId: string;
  @Input() filter: { [parameterName: string]: string};

  returnedTable: SomeObject[];

  onChange: (_: any) => void;
  onTouched: () => void;

  selected: string;

  constructor(private tableService: TableService) { }

  loadTable(): void {
    this.tableService.getTable(this.tableId, this.filter)
      .subscribe(table => {
        this.returnedTable = table;
        if (!!this.select && !!this.select.nativeElement.value) {
          this.writeValue(this.select.nativeElement.value);
          this.onChange(this.selected);
        }
      });
  }

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.loadTable();
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  writeValue(value: string): void {
    if (!!this.returnedTable && !this.returnedTable.some(item => item.value === value)) {
      this.selected = null;
    } else {
      this.selected = value;
    }
  }
}
```

And the `select.component.html` like this:

```
<select class="form-control" #select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
  <option hidden *ngIf="!selected" value=""></option>
  <option *ngFor="let item of returnedTable" [value]="item.value" [selected]="selected === item.value">{{item.value}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's only use valuesChange. If you has two arrays data and subdata and a form like

```
form = new FormGroup({
    prop1: new FormControl(),
    prop2: new FormControl()
  });
```

A simple

```
this.form.get("prop1").valueChanges.subscribe(res => {
  this.dataService.getData(res).subscribe(data=>{
    this.subdata=data;
    if (!this.subdata.find(x=>x.value==this.form.get("prop2").value))
      this.form.get("prop2").setValue(null);
  }).unsubscribe()
});
```

must be enough, see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vetfwn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Is there a way without subscribing to the dataService and by using the `select.component.ts`? In the project I'm facing this problem, the `select.component.ts` is in another module and the validation needs to be done in this module.

Answer (score -1):

To deselect an option:— `option.selected = false`.

Angular library with function decompilation at its core for `$scope` and Nested Forms, an Angular feature that indicates that Angular team doesn't know how to effectively use HTML. HTML doesn't allow nested forms so why the hell would you try to shoehorn the language to do that? More trouble than it's worth. Of course, you can't expect much better from guys like Bradley Green, former Angular JS manager.